# jQuery: finding an element from a list and fadeOut the rest

Tags: jquery, fade

Hei,
 I am kind of new in the jquery family ...  and now I am trying to find an element from a list and  fade out the others. ... I have problems doing that.
 *Here is my html code :

```
   <div class="feature-input">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default add-feature-btn" type="button">Find</button>
        </span>
      </div><!-- /input-group -->
    </div><!--feature-input-->

    <div class="features-list">
      <ul id="the-feature-list" class="feature-list-ul">
        <li>Feature 1 </li>
        <li>Feature 2 </li>
        <li>Feature 3 </li>
        <li>Santa</li>
        <li>Bunny </li>
        <li>Something </li>
        <li>Feature 7 </li>
        <li>Feature 8</li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--featrue-list -->
    </div><!--features-->
```

*And here is my jquery script:

```
  $(".feature-input input").on("keyup", function(e){

        var v = $(this).val();
    if(v){

        $(".feature-list ul li.not-chosen").fadeOut(50);
        $(".feature-list ul li.not-chosen").each(function(){
            if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().match(v.toLowerCase())) 
            {
                $(this).fadeIn(100);
            }
        });
     }
        else{
             $(".feature-list ul li.not-chosen").fadeIn(50);      
    }

  });
```

Can you please tell me what i am doin' wrong, it's starting to drive me crazy.
I am looking for new methods to do this too, i will appreciate any kind of help . ...

Answer (score 1):

You have incorrect selector to target `li` elements. use:

```
$(".feature-input input").on("keyup", function(e){
    var v = $(this).val();
if(v){

    $(".features-list ul li").fadeOut(50);
    $(".features-list ul li").each(function(){
        if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().match(v.toLowerCase())) 
        {
            $(this).fadeIn(100);
        }
    });
 }
    else{
         $(".features-list ul li").fadeIn(50);      
}
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b4b5v828/)**

Answer (score 0):

change this line: "$(".feature-list ul li.not-chosen").fadeOut(50);" to

```
    $(".feature-list ul li").fadeOut(50);
```

this mean fadeOut all the li element before fadeIn the required/this li.